# Angular protractor test presence of modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to test that my sign up modal is presence when clicking the signup button, my problem is that it seems like protractor finish the test before angular is opening the modal and the test fails, **my other solution** is to use Expected Conditions, but for some reason this is not working too, the wait function does not wait the time that i set, the test is running like normal and failed.

```
var SignUpPage = require('./signup.page');

describe('signup page', function() {
  var SignupPage;
  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:9000');
    browser.waitForAngular();
    SignupPage = new SignUpPage();
  });

  it('should open the modal when clicking signup in the main nav', function() {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    SignupPage.clickModalBtn();

    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(SignupPage.getModalEle()), 10000);

    expect(SignupPage.getModalEle().isPresent()).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

The Signuppage:

```
function SignUpPage() {
  this.openModalBtn = element(by.css('.nav-sign-in-btn'));
  this.modal = element(by.css('.reSkill-auth'));
  this.email = element(by.css('input[type="email"'));
  this.password = element(by.css('input[type="password"'));
  this.signInBtn = element(by.css('button[type="submit"]'));
}

SignUpPage.prototype.clickModalBtn = function() {
  this.openModalBtn.click();
}

SignUpPage.prototype.getModalEle = function() {
  return this.modal;
}

SignUpPage.prototype.setEmailAndPassword = function() {
  this.email.sendkeys('mail@gmail.com');
  this.password.sendkeys('123456789');
}

SignUpPage.prototype.clickSignIn = function() {
  this.signInBtn.click();
}

module.exports = SignUpPage;
```

How can i test this?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code of `SignupPage`, especially `getModalEle`?

Comment: I added the signup code

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might help is to increase the *default jasmine timeout interval*:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000  // 60 seconds
}
```